# My father and my birthday/My father's birthday and mine/My father's and my birthday...something else?

Tags: adjectives, possessives

As an esl teacher I'm a bit embarrassed about this one. I have some groups on WhatsApp to practice English and in one of them a student put: "Today is birthday of my father and my."

What would the correct sentence be? Thanks for your time. I love this site!

Answer (score 2):

Try

> My and my father's birthday.

It's still a tad awkward sounding, but there's no perfect way out of this particular linguistic cul-de-sac in English.

Note: never use *my* except as a possessive pronoun. Say "Today is the birthday of my father and **me**," never "my father and **my**."

Comment: As you say, there's no perfect way, but [me and my twin's birthday](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22me+and+my+twin%27s+birthday%22) seems like the best of a bad bunch. [Delorna wanted to make her and her twin's birthday as pleasant as possible.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Delorna+wanted+to+make+her+and+her+twin%27s+birthday+as+pleasant+as+possible%22)

Comment: So you would use *me* as a possessive pronoun? Curious. At best, that usage would be dialectical, not standard English.

Comment: I never actually thought to search for [**my** and my twin's birthday](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22my+and+my+twin%27s+birthday%22) when posting that first comment. There was only one hit for ***my*** version (I mean the version that sounds better to ***me***, obviously! :) but there are none at all for your (=my) version. Insignificant, perhaps, given the minuscule sample size, but one might have expected some grammarian to be drumming it into us that we should say *my and my twin's* rather than *me and my twin's* if they really had the courage of their convictions.

Comment: In the long run I don't think OP has anything to gain by allowing himself to be convinced that either of our two versions is "correct" or "dialectal". All he really needs to recognise is that competent native speakers may disagree or be uncertain about what's "best" or "most natural". So he's no reason to feel embarrassed, since in practical terms, *his* opinion is as good as anyone else's in this matter.

Comment: @Fumble: That feels like sophistry. If his opinion is as good as anyone else's, what is the value of this site?

Comment: Well, the OP here obviously didn't *know* that there's no perfect way out of this particular linguistic cul-de-sac until you pointed it out, so I'd have thought both your answer *and* our comments here would be useful information. But I really don't understand where you're coming from on this one. Are you trying to imply that you think *my* comments are erroneous/misleading?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence in the question would be better as

> Today is **the** birthday of my father and **me**.

Another way to say this awkward sentence is

> Today is my birthday and my father's.

with the sentence left dangling, its meaning obvious. However I was taught not to mention myself in a sentence before others (a matter of manners), so another way could be

> Today is my father's birthday and mine.

And going off a bit:

> My father and I share the same birthday, which is today!

Comment: "Going off a bit" is the right thing to do here. Rephrasing and paraphrasing is often the best solution if a sentence feels awkward.

Comment: If "Today is the birthday of my father and me" is the best way, I don't want to be right! :) I'm going to suggest that they rephrase as in most of these answers that seems like the best sounding option. Thanks to all.

Comment: I didn't say it is the best way. I began the answer with a grammatical version of the sentence in the body of your question. My opinion of the best way, is the last sentence in my answer.

Comment: How about *Today is the birthday of my father's and mine.*?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of these only:

- Today is our birthday. Mine and my father's.
- Today I and my father have a birthday.
- Today it's my father's birthday and mine too.